# Solaris 11 XOpenDisplay return NULL

Tags: solaris, system-calls, xserver

I am getting problem while running following program over Solaris 11. The XOpenDisplay function always return NULL. The same program run fine over Solaris 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Display *ptr = 0;


    ptr = XOpenDisplay("machine_name:0.0");

    if (0 == ptr)
    {
        printf("NULL received\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Valid pointer received\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

During investigation I have found that the Solaris 11 do not accept direct X11 connections by using the TCP protocol.
I have enabled the TCP for X11-server using the following command.

```
svccfg -s x11-server setprop options/tcp_listen=true
```

But during calling the function XOpenDisplay still returns the NULL and now I am getting the error as "no protocol specified".

Answer (score 0):

Can you open a connection with a simple X client such as `xclock` or `xdpyinfo` with `$DISPLAY` set to `machine_name:0.0` - until you can do that, you have a configuration error in your X setup, and need to fix that before you can find if your code is working or not.

Are you logged into the X session on the Solaris 11 machine?   Did it store the xauth cookies in `$HOME/.Xauthority` or is it using the new gdm default of setting `$XAUTHORITY` to a local file in /tmp that isn't visible to other machines?   If so, you may need to copy the xauth cookie for that machine to `$HOME/.Xauthority` or a file on the remote system that you set `$XAUTHORITY` to point to.

BTW, we mainly recommend using `ssh -X` to make remote X connections these days, and to take care of setting the DISPLAY environment variable, xauth cookies, and handling security for you, so you don't have to do that all yourself.

Comment: :I have logged directly into the X session on Solaris 11. My application is running over the same host machine and opening the connection with same host using hostname:0.0. If I give the command ssh -X username@host_name then the application runs properly and able to open the connection with X server. But I have to give this command every time I open the new terminal. How should I configure the authentication using .Xauthority? Do you have any oracle link for sharing?